# Recyclerview with inside nested scrollview?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, nestedscrollview

I am using multiple View-holder inside recycler which placed inside nested scroll view,There is a change in Natural behaviour of **onBindViewHolder()** Recycler view because of Nested Scroll,**getItemViewType()** all items are called inside **onBindViewHolder()** when initiate recycler adapter,For Example I have 20 Items means in normal scenario only three items called when initiate,but in case of nested scroll view all 20 views create on first load.

Xml File

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/light_gray_vd">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:contentScrim="@color/primaryColor"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="16dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/inc_gallery"
                    layout="@layout/proj_galery_new"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </FrameLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_header_view"
                    layout="@layout/header_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/vde_mv_scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlCollapseScroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/view_recycler"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>



        </FrameLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Recyclerview  inside Scrollview is never a good idea. I'm assuming you gave Recyclerview fixed height. I think that where the problem is.

Comment: @Hein I used only wrap content,but nested scroll view allot full space for recycler

Comment: Can you put up said layout file ?

Comment: I see you are using CoordinatorLayout with CollapsingToolbarLayout. You want to collapse toolbar by scrolling recyclerview ?

Comment: @Hein yes I need to collapse with recycler view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102879/discussion-between-hein-and-appukrb).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove `NestedScrollView` and `frameLayout`, and set `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` for `recycleView`
 like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/light_gray_vd">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:contentScrim="@color/primaryColor"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="16dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/inc_gallery"
                    layout="@layout/proj_galery_new"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </FrameLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_header_view"
                    layout="@layout/header_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/view_recycler"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                android:scrollbars="vertical">

            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is both `Recyclerview` and `NestedScrollview` are scrollable. By removing one, you should be able to achieve the effect you wanted.

So, try using only `Recyclerview` **without** putting it inside `NestedScrollView`. Like this :

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/light_gray_vd"
    >
  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
      android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
      >

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:contentScrim="@color/primaryColor"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="16dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        >

      <FrameLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
          app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
          >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/inc_gallery"
            layout="@layout/proj_galery_new"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

      </FrameLayout>

      <View
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
          />

      <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
          android:id="@+id/toolbar1"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
          android:layout_gravity="top"
          app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
          app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
          >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_header_view"
            layout="@layout/header_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            />
      </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

  </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
      android:id="@+id/view_recycler"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

You can also reference [this example](http://pulse7.net/android/how-to-create-collapsing-toolbar-layout-like-whatsapp-in-android-application/) or read this [article from Code path about how to handle scroll with CoordinatorLayout](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout)

[CheeseSquare from Chris Bane](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare) also has a good CoordinatorLayout example

Answer (score 0):

I also had same issue after Android Support Library 23.2.0 update.

Set `RecyclerView`'s `android:layout_height` to `match_parent`.

And disable new automeasure feature ([read more](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/support-library/index.html#revisions)):

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), 
    LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
layoutManager.setAutoMeasureEnabled(false);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Comment: OnBindViewHolder() is not calling and view is not rendering