# Android recyclerview v.23.2.0 & design library v.23.2.0 are broken

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-recyclerview, android-support-design

After update to v23.2.0 recyclerview items have strange behavior: very big with empty space. After update to design library 23.2.0 menu overflow icon became black (app has dark action bar).

**UPDATE**
On my nexus 5 overflow icon & recycler view row are fixed, but on Galaxy Tab 4 overflow icon is still black.

**UPDATE 2**
If you have problems with empty spacing, fix layout parameters for your views (match_parent -> wrap_content), cause RecyclerView will now size itself based on the size of its contents. 
Read this blog 
http://android-developers.blogspot.am/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html

> The RecyclerView widget provides an advanced and flexible base for creating lists and grids as well as supporting animations. This release brings an exciting new feature to the LayoutManager API: auto-measurement! This allows a RecyclerView to size itself based on the size of its contents. This means that previously unavailable scenarios, such as using WRAP_CONTENT for a dimension of the RecyclerView, are now possible. You’ll find all built in LayoutManagers now support auto-measurement.
>
> Due to this change, make sure to double check the layout parameters of
>   your item views: previously ignored layout parameters (such as
>   MATCH_PARENT in the scroll direction) will now be fully respected.

**UPDATE 3**
Link to the issue that describes the problem with black icons in Action Bar
[Issue 201918](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=201918)

**UPDATE 4**
See my answer under post, icons problem is also solved

Comment: Change your adapter xml file.

Comment: add some screen explain well because its worked as expected at our end

Comment: Plz update support v4 and appcompat to 23.2.

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar Please see update.

Comment: @tinysunlight all libs are updated

Comment: @android_dev: yes there is issue. current solution is http://stackoverflow.com/a/28631979/1168654 w'll find appropriate solution update and you soon

Comment: for overflow menu http://stackoverflow.com/a/32108151/1168654

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar ok, thanks, but before update to 23.2.0 that worked fine

Comment: @android_dev what did you do to fix Recyclerview items with empty space??

Comment: @Raghunandan my layout root's height was set to match_parent, changed it to wrap_content

Comment: I also have problems... back arrow in toolbar became black with 23.2 and one of tablayouts is not showing tab names...

Comment: It was fixed with [23.2.1](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/tools/support-library/index.html#revisions). We no longer need set **`vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true`**.

Comment: @hata Thanks for info, will give it a try!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The reason you are getting large open spaces is because of match_parent. It wasn't working correctly before, but now with the new release it is working differently. You just need to update to wrap_content instead of match_parent as that causes the layout to match the parent giving you the large spaces.

> The RecyclerView widget provides an advanced and flexible base for creating lists and grids as well as supporting animations. This release brings an exciting new feature to the LayoutManager API: auto-measurement! This allows a RecyclerView to size itself based on the size of its contents. This means that previously unavailable scenarios, such as using WRAP_CONTENT for a dimension of the RecyclerView, are now possible. You’ll find all built in LayoutManagers now support auto-measurement.

http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html

Comment: Thanks for info, I have already fixed that. See my comment under original question :)

Comment: I actually have a new problem with recyclerviews inside swiperefresh layouts. Scrolling up isn't possible as it tries to refresh. The fun of support library updates :/

Comment: I came across that too. It seems to be a regressive of a bug fixed in 23.1.1. Hopefully Google will update these libraries asap.

Comment: Also I had an issue with `RecyclerView` scrolling. It`s solved by `recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)`.

Comment: @mixel Thanks for that comment. I don't find setNestedScrollingEnabled helps with my scrolling issue :/

Comment: @JamesBritton I had different issue than yours. Finally I solved it (http://stackoverflow.com/a/35865822/746347).

Comment: I would like to note that I had to use wrap_content on the items layout of the RecyclerView. Not on the RecyclerView itself. This fixed my issue.

Comment: @RadoslavYordanov that is what I was originally referring to, the items not the recyclerview.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that two new libraries, support-vector-drawable and support-animated-vector-drawable, are **required**, because appcompat-v7 uses vector drawables ([Issue discussion](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=201851)). Just update your build.gradle with the following for adding in support for vector drawables and **the problem with black icons will be solved**.

**build.gradle**

Add following lines to your build gradle base on your gradle plugin version

// Gradle Plugin 2.0+

```
 android {  
   defaultConfig {  
     vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  
    }  
 }
```

// Gradle Plugin 1.5

```
 android {  
   defaultConfig {  
     generatedDensities = []  
  }  

  // This is handled for you by the 2.0+ Gradle Plugin  
  aaptOptions {  
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"  
  }  
 }
```

**UPDATE**
For AppCompat users, the flags for enabling support vector drawables described in the 23.2 [blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.am/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html) are no longer required for usage of AppCompat 23.2.1. However, you can still take advantage of the app:srcCompat attribute if you wish to use support vector drawables for your own resources.